# CC3200 RTOS MultiThreading

Tags: c, multithreading, multitasking, texas-instruments, osi

I'm new to the RTOS method of creating tasks. Previously, I was using a pthread on the Raspberry Pi, which enable me to run 2 tasks simultaneously at the same time,

1) to send data through sockets every 2 seconds

2) to receive data through sockets whenever data is being sent from client

I'd like to do the same thing, but CC3200 is currently running on RTOS and I read that you can only pause tasks and run another one, but I need to have both running at the same time.

I tried to do this:

```
osi_TaskCreate( WlanAPMode, \
                        (const signed char*)"wireless LAN in AP mode", \
                        OSI_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL );
osi_TaskCreate( SendAnalogInputToClient, "Analog Input to Client",\
                                OSI_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL );
osi_start();
```

But it seems that my 2nd task isn't running. Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're misunderstanding is the general concept of concurrency and execution of tasks/threads.

Both Raspberry Pi and CC3200 have a single core processor - that is, their processing units are capable of executing only one instruction at a time. Unlike modern computers which may have several cores and sometimes can execute twice as much threads by using hyperthreading, the single core processors do not allow to execute more than one instruction at any given time due to their design.

What you’ve done using Raspberry Pi was simply running multiple “threads” that the OS (Raspbian I assume) executed “concurrently”. I put those in quotation marks as they were not real threads and the concurrency wasn’t real. You just had an impression of concurrency, as both programs shared processor time, though the core executed only one program at a time. It is the OS job to switch between the two “threads” and make an impression of concurrency. It is a so called context switch when a processing unit switches to another task and loads its context to its registers.

The same is happening in the case of CC3200 and SYS/BIOS TI-RTOS. Only one task is executed at any given moment. It’s the programmer (or architect) job to design the system so that all the tasks are given as much processing time as they need to execute properly.

Your code isn’t really helpful here, as you’re starting the tasks correctly. It’s the task source codes that are the problem. I assume your first task never sleeps/delays/blocks and it consumes 100% of the processing time. That’s why your second task never gets a chance to run.

This is a good place to start: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SYS/BIOS_Online_Training